# How to sort and rank and select a unique value?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I need to get the rank, from a group of players by sorting using sql query.

i have the query.

```
query = @"SET @rank=0; 
           SELECT player_ID,player_name,HP,@rank:=@rank+1 As Rank 
           FROM player_profile ORDER BY HP DESC;"
```

the problem is i just need the specified player's rank from this query.

Since rank is generated using SQL, i can't use WHERE clause. That will one bring one player from DB, resulting one rank.

I tried to get all of them into a datatable and then filter the single value out of it.

```
con.Open();
        MySqlDataAdapter dt = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable tt = new DataTable();            
        string query = @"SET @rank=0; 
           SELECT player_ID,player_name,HP,@rank:=@rank+1 As Rank 
           FROM player_profile ORDER BY HP DESC;";
        MySqlCommand cm1 = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        dt.SelectCommand = cm1;
        dt.Fill(tt);            
        con.Close();
        DataRow[] foundRows = tt.Select("player_name=" + Label2.Text); // Error:Cannot find column ["Column name"]
        foreach (DataRow dr in foundRows)
        {
            Label32.Text = dr["Rank"].ToString();
        }
```

this is how my table looks
http://pastebin.com/7KWJ9bn3

any help is appreciated.

Comment: SELECT * FROM(SELECT player_ID,player_name,HP,@rank:=@rank+1 As Rank 
           FROM player_profile ORDER BY HP DESC) where.....

Comment: Why do you need to calculate the rank in the sql? Can't you do this in code by adding one to the index position? This has the added benefit of removing what seems like business logic from your data access layer

Comment: If you downvote someone just because you don't understand, then that's not their mistake... ask... clear your doubt... then answer that's how this work... not just downvoting and moving on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about selecting from the resulting table?

```
string query = @"SET @rank=0; 
Select a.Rank from (SELECT player_ID,@rank:=@rank+1 As Rank 
   FROM player_profile ORDER BY HP DESC) a where player_ID=@1";
```

Comment: Edit your answer to this and will accept http://pastebin.com/CbnD9WzK i modified your answer a little.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big proponent of not putting business logic in your SQL which it seems like your doing here. The below code is my updated version of your code which should be logically equivalent without having to do any calculation on the SQL side of things.

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve (is this example code?) so if you can provide more info I can refine this some more, but again this will do the exact same thing in a "better" fashion.

```
con.Open();
        MySqlDataAdapter dt = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable tt = new DataTable();            
        string query = @"SET @rank=0; 
           SELECT player_ID,player_name,HP
           FROM player_profile ORDER BY HP DESC;";
        MySqlCommand cm1 = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        dt.SelectCommand = cm1;
        dt.Fill(tt);            
        con.Close();
        DataRow[] foundRows = tt.Select("player_name=" + Label2.Text); // Error:Cannot find column ["Column name"]
        int count = 1;
        foreach (DataRow dr in foundRows)
        {
            Label32.Text = count;//dr["Rank"].ToString();
            count++;
        }
```